# Problem starting DHIS@ using sample PostgreSQL db - HTTP ERROR: 503

Tags: dhis2

I downloaded the dhis2-db-sierra-leone.sql db and imported it into PostreSQL 9.4 running on Windows 8.1. I have configured the dhis.conf as:

```
#hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
#hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.h2.Driver
#hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:h2:./database/dhis2;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
#hibernate.connection.username = sa
#hibernate.connection.password =

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql:dhis2
hibernate.connection.username = dhis
hibernate.connection.password = dhis

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
```

When I run the start I get 503 error:

> HTTP ERROR: 503
>   Problem accessing /. Reason:
>       Service Unavailable
>   Powered by Jetty://

In the log file, I'm getting this:

```
* INFO  2016-12-22 15:27:01,449 'system-process' update org.hisp.dhis.dataelement.DataElementCategory, name: default, uid: vGs6omsRekv (AuditLogUtil.java [Thread-2])
* ERROR 2016-12-22 15:27:01,544 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [ORGANISATION_UNIT] for enum class [org.hisp.dhis.common.ValueType]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:433)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have an invalid value in the "dataelement" and/or "trackedentityattribute" tables for the valuetype column. The valid values are these:

TEXT
LONG_TEXT,
LETTER,
PHONE_NUMBER,
EMAIL,
BOOLEAN,
TRUE_ONLY,
DATE,
DATETIME,
TIME,
NUMBER,
UNIT_INTERVAL,
PERCENTAGE,
INTEGER,
INTEGER_POSITIVE,
INTEGER_NEGATIVE,
INTEGER_ZERO_OR_POSITIVE,
TRACKER_ASSOCIATE,
USERNAME,
FILE_RESOURCE,
COORDINATE,
ORGANISATION_UNIT,
AGE

Replace all values which are not among these.